# Netbeans code folding for HTML files?

Tags: macos, html, netbeans, netbeans-7.1

I've looked for anything about how to fold the code down in HTML files using Netbeans. Does anyone know? I'm on a Mac using Netbeans 7.1.1 and I've already hit up the Preferences>General area... am I missing something here? Any help for this newbie would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Code folding is already enabled on elements in an HTML file. You can collapse the individual tags, or groups of tags.

[image: Code Folding in XHTML Page]

Comment: However Netbeans has extra features in java like the default folding and text e.g. //  <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="loads of lines are hidden here">...code...// </editor-fold>